# Unable to install language in Joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I'm trying to install another language on my Joomla site, but when I want to do it a message accurs:

*There are no available languages to install at the moment. Please click on the "Find languages" button to check for updates on the Joomla Languages server. You will need an internet connection for this to work.*

Is there a way to install it manually?

Comment: Hi Stefan! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

sure you can:

1. Go check this link. 
   http://community.joomla.org/translations/joomla-3-translations.html
2. Install the language pack via extension manager

voila :)